# What can category theory encode that set theory could not encode, if anything? (Fwd from Quora)

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

Interesting reply to [this question at Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-can-category-theory-encode-that-set-theory-could-not-encode-if-anything?) from Alex Sadovsky, Ph.D. Mathematics & Biomechanics, University of California, Irvine

> Nothing. All of modern mathematics is described in the language of
>   [naive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_set_theory). Every area of mathematics, whether
>   category theory, representation theory, functional analysis, or
>   algebraic geometry, is just a specialization. It does not introduce
>   anything that could not be described by set theory.
>
> Category theory specializes in Morphisms.

Comments from readers here?

Comment: I mean, categories can be (and are usually) described in terms of set theory, so clearly anything that can be encoded with categories can also be encoded with sets.

Comment: “I recall that, at the 1963 meeting devoted to Logic, Methodology and Philosophy of Science in Jerusalem, Bill Lawvere proposed basing mathematics on categories rather than sets. Alfred Tarski, who was in the audience, objected: what is a category if not a set of objects and a set of arrows? Lawvere replied: set theory deals with the binary relation of membership, category theory with the ternary relation of composition. Apparently, Tarski was satisfied with the answer.”

Comment: Can you link to the Quora question?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Link added.

Comment: Please don't post "fwd from Quora" stuff here. If you have a question, ask the question. This is not a site to "get comments" or "encourage discussion". It's a Q&A site.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Would you have preferred, "Is this true?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is right, and we can make this precise. As [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3608426/can-we-build-set-theory-from-category-theory/3608471#3608471) says as well, there is the [Elementary Theory of the Category of Sets (ETCS)](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS), which is in the language of category theory, and there is [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory), the well-known axiomatisation of set theory. ZFC is really stronger than ETCS, the answer I linked goes in more detail, but point is that we can add axioms (a variant of replacement) to ETCS to make it in fact equiconsistent with ZFC.

**Edit.** From a comment from Noah Schweber: a survey of possibly-relevant weaker fragments of ZFC can be found [here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/maclane.pdf). I thought this might be relevant to point out here as well.

**Edit 2.** Upon reading the Quora answer again I should say that I agree with the technical part of the answer, namely that set theory and category theory can encode the same things. That was the point of my answer here. I do *not* agree that everything in mathematics is a "specialisation" of (naive) set theory. For example, I highly doubt many mathematicians view the natural numbers as the [von Neumann ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals).

Comment: If it would be necessary to add axioms to the ETCS in order to make it equivalent to the ZFC, does that not imply that the ETCS is more general and set theory is a special case with more restrictions? Which would mean that the answer is wrong, i.e. the ETCS can not be captured in the framework of set theory?

Comment: @FelixB. There's a difference between *framework* and *specific theory*. ZF lacks the axiom of choice; does that mean ZF can't be captured in the framework of ZFC? The point is that ETCS fits, up to appropriate equivalence, into a "context of theories" which ZFC-style set theory captures exactly. (A survey of possibly-relevant weaker fragments of ZFC can be found [here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/maclane.pdf).)

Comment: Although that said, I take huge issue with the "almost equiconsistent" bit - dropping replacement results in a *gigantic* loss of consistency strength. The right thing to compare ETCS to if I recall correctly is Z (or ZC). To see the drop in consistency strength, keep in mind that ZFC proves that $V_\lambda\models ZC$ for every infinite limit cardinal $\lambda$. This doesn't affect the broad point of the answer of course, since Z itself is a ZFC-style set theory, but I think it's worth noting.

Comment: Given that everything proved in a certain framework essentially requires the axioms as assumptions (i.e. you are not proving $A \implies B$, you are really proving (without properly stating it) that $A+\text{ZFC} \implies B$), then the set of true statements in the framework of ZF is a subset of the set of true statements in the framework of ZFC. So ZF can not be captured in ZFC in that sense. Since some statements in the framework of ZFC might be wrong in ZF. While you could just add the missing assumption in ZF to get the statement from ZFC

Comment: @FelixB. That's a very narrow interpretation of "framework," in my opinion. Note, for example, that ZFC isn't even explicitly mentioned in the question. (Also I think you either mean "subset" in place of "superset" or "consistent" in place of "true".)

Comment: @NoahSchweber yeah just noticed and edited it. How would you interpret framework? I just figured that interpreting axioms as "implied assumptions in every statement left out for readability", makes the most sense

Comment: @FelixB. As referring to the choice of language and basic organizing ideas (which is of course subjective). E.g. [NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations) uses the same language as ZF, but *not* the same framework since the latter is heavily driven by the idea of a **cumulative hierarchy** while the former ... *really* isn't. To a certain extent, at least in the context of set theories the basic organizing ideas largely reflect the "Russell response:" NF responds to Russell's paradox by limiting comprehension to *stratified* formulas, while ZFC responds with "hierarchy + separation."

Comment: FWIW, here Replacement plays an interesting role: we need to add Replacement to ZC in order to get the cumulative hierarchy to behave well. For example, ZC alone can't prove that $V_\omega$ exists. The hierarchical idea is present in ZC, but it's not "polished" yet. Does this mean that ZC fails to live up to its own framework? I'd argue that the answer is **no**, but this is an interesting point. But for this question it doesn't matter since we can fix ZC in this sense without significantly increasing its strength; this is (one of the things) treated in the paper linked in my original comment.

Comment: Here is roughly where I am out of my depth. If I understand you correctly ZFC solves issues like russels set by posing that some sets simply do not exist, and that sets have to be possible to be composed from the ground up with certain rules in order to exist, while NF allows some larger sets to exists and solves russels set problem by preventing the use of certain statements in comprehension. In short: ZFC limits composition, while NF limits comprehension. So they are more "fundamentally different". Correct? (Haven't quite understood stratification yet)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for your comments, I have linked the survey you mentioned in my answer and changed the wording "almost equiconsistent" to "not quite equiconsistent". Hopefully that is more appropriate.

Comment: I have also added a comment about the claim that everything is a 'specialisation' of (naive) set theory.

Comment: @MarkKamsma Honestly I still think that doesn't do it justice - the gulf is **gigantic**, there's really no comparison in terms of strength.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Third time is the charm? I did not want to focus too much on the exact consequences of losing replacement. The point I really wanted to make is that we can easily formulate a theory ETCS$^+$ in the language of category theory which is equiconsistent with ZFC, which is how I interpreted OP's question.

Comment: @NoahSchweber ZC can't prove $V_\omega$ exists? Somehow that surprises me even though I can see both the usual routes to its construction break. Is there a simple countermodel?

Comment: @NoahSchweber It seems to go against the widely circulated claim that most math can be done without replacement. Not cause we need HF per se, but because it's just a closure under some simple operations... something that comes up all the time. I'm sure there's a workaround for doing things like this without replacement... I clearly haven't thought about this enough.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen We definitely can do most math without replacement. E.g. the usual example of a "bad model" of Z is $V_{\omega+\omega}$. In $V_{\omega+\omega}$, there are no ordinals $\ge\omega+\omega$. However, there absolutely **are** long well-orderings even if AC fails in our metatheory: already in $V_{\omega+2}$ we get the set of equivalence classes of well-orderings on $\omega$, and then in $V_{\omega+3}$ we get the natural well-ordering of *that* set. This is fairly standard for how this goes: the "canonical constructions" in ZF don't work, but a bit messier construction will suffice.

Comment: As to a model of Z + "$HF$ doesn't exist," I don't know one off the top of my head but I think Mathias' paper describes one.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: You can construct a structure that is _isomorphic_ to $(V_\omega,\in)$ in ZC.  You just can't get a structure where the relation is actually $\in$ itself.  So from the perspective of "ordinary" mathematics where you only care about studying structures up to isomorphism, you can do pretty much everything you might care about as long as you don't need any sets whose cardinality is too big (basically, anything that involves strictly increasing an infinite cardinality infinitely many times).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yeah, I've come to terms with the whole no-von-neumann-ordinals thing, but just kind of struck by there not being a closure of $\{\emptyset\}$ under union and pairing.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yeah, like how there's no $\omega+\omega,$ but definitely well-orderings of that type, makes sense. But can you help me out with how to reconcile the fact that a simple closure under a few operations doesn't exist? (What is the isomorphic thing that does exist?)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: Well, for instance, you can define a relation $R$ on $\omega$ such that $(\omega,R)\cong (V_\omega,\in)$, by encoding the combinatorics of hereditarily finite sets with numbers in any of the usual ways.

Comment: @EricWofsey Right, right, Ackermann coding, makes sense. And I suppose any closure of a finite set under a finite set of functions can be handled by something similar.

Comment: @Noah: If my memory serves me right, and it's early in the morning so it might not, ETCS is bi-interpretable with *bounded* Zermelo.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, it should be bounded Zermelo (at least according to Sheaves in Geometry and Logic, section IV.10). It is not quite a bi-interpretation though. There are technical details on the set-theoretic side, which can be fixed by adding an axiom (see the end of mentioned section). Also on the category-theoretic side we don't quite get an isomorphic category back, just an equivalent one. This again can be fixed, for example by requiring the category to be a skeleton (ugly from a category-theoretic point of view, but well).